# How can I fix this linker problem in Clang when compiling a C program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile a C program with Clang. While building, it is showing the error message linker command failed to execute with exit code 1.

How can I solve this?

I'm using Windows 10. I have installed the latest version of [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM). I'm trying to compile the program with the command line.

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using this command

```
clang main.c  -o main.exe -v
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
   "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.11.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\7.1.0" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\7.1.0\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\WDExpress\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.17763.0\\ucrt" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\shared" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\um" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.17763.0\\winrt" -fdebug-compilation-dir "C:\\Users\\amith.ks\\Desktop" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 120 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.11 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o "C:\\Users\\amith.ks\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\main-ecf8c2.o" -x c main.c
clang -cc1 version 7.1.0 based upon LLVM 7.1.0 default target x86_64-pc-win32
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.1.0\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt
End of search list.
 "link.exe" -out:main.exe -defaultlib:libcmt "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\WDExpress\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.17763.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.17763.0\\um\\x64" -nologo "C:\\Users\\amith.ks\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\main-ecf8c2.o"

clang.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not able to get that linker error. What is it is looking for?

Comment: Can you post the command you're using in the command line?

Comment: How do you build the program? What is the exact error you get? Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete command you write and output you get.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It seems you don't have updated the `%PATH%` to where Clang is installed, so the command-prompt don't know where to find the `clang.exe` program.

Comment: I have already set the path while installing only.

Comment: Please check whether you have any unwanted symbols associated with your PATH variable

Comment: Hmm, thinking about a little, you should get a different error if the program wasn't found. Instead it seems to be a problem invoking the linker program. Please do as the error message suggest (run with the `-v` option added) and edit your question to include the full output of that.

Comment: It might mean that `clang.exe` is trying to invoke the linker but cannot find the program because `link.exe` is not in `%PATH%`.

Comment: so what is that link.exe it is trying to find.so that i can add it to system path

Answer (score 2):

*link.exe* is Microsoft Visual C++'s (MSVC) linker.
It does not come with Clang, and you should install it by installing Visual C++.

Note that *link.exe* does not necessarily need to be in PATH, clang seems to have some autodetection capabilities.

If it is already installed, that could mean that clang failed to locate your MSVC installation. In this case, updating your PATH with your MSVC installation directory, or calling *vcvarsall.bat* before using Clang could solve your issue.

Comment: I already installed visual studio express 2017. I can see that link.exe is present in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\WDExpress\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x64" Path . I set its path to environment variable.

Comment: Have you tried calling `link.exe` yourself from the command line?

Comment: Yes i got list of some names like this  /DLL
      /DRIVER[:{UPONLY|WDM}]
      /DYNAMICBASE[:NO]
      /ENTRY:symbol

Comment: Can you try to run the 2 commands clang is running in the background `"C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe" -cc1 -triple ...` and `"link.exe" -out:main.exe -defaultlib:libcmt ...`

Comment: Is Windows SDK missing a problem here? .Is that a problem for all of this.? I can c one folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin path  NETFX 4.6.1 Tools folder only..

Comment: @amithks Nothing is impossible, but that would be very surprising given that clang complains about link.exe which is part of MSVC not Windows SDK. Have you tried to run the commands manually?

Comment: Yes For link.exe ..error was---->       LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\\Users\\amith.ks\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\main-ecf8c2.o'. I opened task manager i was not able to find execuatable files.

Comment: @amithks Please make sure that `main-ecf8c2.o` does exist after you run the first clang command and before you run the link command. To make it easier, you can replace the full `'C:\\Users\\amith.ks\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\main-ecf8c2.o'` path by just `main.o` in both commands, it will generate the main.o in the current folder, it is easier to check for it.

Comment: I executed first command and also second command seperately.i got main.o and main.exe... i tried to open main.exe .it wont show even for 1 ms..like automatically closing it is.

Comment: @amithks That's the normal behavior on Windows when you open a console app from explorer. Try to run it from a cmd prompt

Comment: Now everything works fine. But everytime I have to run that long commads?Is it always take ```-target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu```.as standard library?

Comment: @amithks No, normally you should be able to do it in a single command: `clang -o main.exe main.c`. You should also be able to do it in 2 simple commands: `clang -o main.o -c main.c` and `clang -o main.exe main.o`. The fact that it works when you type the 2 long commands but not with the short one makes me think that you have an issue with your clang installation/configuration. Maybe you can try with clang 8 and/or msvc2019 to see if you have any difference.

Comment: Now everything works fine now .```clang main.c -o main.exe -target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.11.0``` giving error for stdio.h file ..But works fine for ```clang main.c -o main.exe -target i686-pc-windows-gnu```.How to use target msvc and exclude gnu.?

Comment: ```"C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe" -cc1 -triple... main.o" -x c main.c``` This works fine. But the simple ```clang main.c -o main.o``` give ```fatal error:stdio.h cannot be found ``` is getting.

Comment: @amithks open a new question as this is not the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this answer. But there are a lot of differences between the [Visual Studio Community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2017) and [Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#2012%E2%80%932017:_Ecosystem-centric) edition.

I installed Visual Studio Community and dependency tools like MSVC, WINDOWS SDK, etc. And added `link.exe` to `%PATH%`. Everything worked fine.